# ASP.NET MVC - partialview - codebehind?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am used to ASP.NET where each user control would have its own codebehind, and you do things related to that usercontrol in that codebehind C#.net file, so you can reference the usercontrol anywhere you like.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, and I added an ascx control, and I can not seem to figure out where do I write the code for setting viewdata specific to that control?  I have this ascx control inside my master page, so the setting up for viewdata for that control should be at such a place that is available to all pages, so I can not do it inside Index() or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a partial view (.ascx) that has its own controller ("code-behind") associated with it, consider using `RenderAction()` rather than `RenderPartial()`.

http://blogs.intesoft.net/post/2009/02/renderaction-versus-renderpartial-aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: @kilonet: RenderAction is also in the MVC Futures assembly of version 1.0 (Microsoft.Web.Mvc)

Comment: The link to http://blogs.intesoft.net/post/2009/02/renderaction-versus-renderpartial-aspnet-mvc.aspx appears to be dead.  These may be alternative resources: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/11/24/renderpartial-vs-renderaction.aspx  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/